# How to use boolean from different if statements and use them to change code

Tags: jquery

```
$('#1').on('click', function(){
  var changeClonedTitle = true;
});
$('#2').on('click', function(){
  var changeClonedTitle = false;
});

if(changeClonedTitle == true) {
// code here
}
if(changeClonedTitle == false) {
// other code here
}
```

Nothing happens, it doesn't catch the status of the boolean inside the last 2 `if statements` to change code.

Why does this happen(i know i am a noob). Using Jquery.

Hope that someone can help me, i appreciate the time and effort.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements will only run *once*, at the beginning of pageload. If you want them to run every time a click occurs, put the logic inside the callback. Change to

```
$('#1').on('click', function(){
  // code here
});
$('#2').on('click', function(){
  // other code here
});
```

without any `changeClonedTitle` variable.